# Why can't I use the same method twice for one instance in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this program that basically uses a method called reverse_complement to  reverse a string and replaces some characters with other characters; However, if I use the method twice for the same instance it gives me an undefined error. So, puts dna1.reverse_complement.reverse_complement == dna1.nucleotide should give me a true value. However, it gives an undefined method error.

```
class DNA
  attr_reader :nucleotide

  def initialize (nucleotide)
     @nucleotide = nucleotide
  end
  def reverse_complement()
    @nucleotide.reverse.tr("ATCG", "TAGC")
  end

end
dna1 = DNA.new("ATTGCC")
puts dna1.reverse_complement

puts dna1.nucleotide

puts dna2 = dna1.reverse_complement


puts dna1.reverse_complement.reverse_complement == dna1.nucleotide
```

Comment: Please unnaccept my answer so I can delete it because it's not the correct way of doing things. Please see http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this suffice?:

```
class DNA < String
  def reverse_complement
    reverse.tr("ATCG", "TAGC")
  end
end

dna1 = DNA.new("ATTGCC")
puts dna1
# ATTGCC
puts dna1.reverse_complement 
# GGCAAT
puts dna1.reverse_complement.reverse_complement == dna1
# true
```

#### Notes

```
def reverse_complement
  reverse.tr("ATCG", "TAGC")
end
```

can be written as:

```
def reverse_complement
  self.reverse.tr("ATCG", "TAGC")
end
```

where `self` is the current object. In the examples above, `self` is `dna1` which is an instance of DNA.

---

*caveat: inheriting from core classes is a bad idea. This answer will be deleted if OP kindly unaccepts this answer. See [link](http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes) for more details about inheriting from core classes.*

Comment: Is it really a good idea to inherit from the String class seeing as ruby has single class inheritance? Why doesn't he just define a `to_s` method that returns `@nucleotide`, that way `puts dna1 => # ATTGCC`

Comment: @BlackEnigma I was just trying to give the OP what they wanted (chaining). I had a feeling I'd be called up on inheriting from String. I am going to delete this answer.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. That's perfectly understandable. I don't think there is any need to delete the answer as it does work and the user is satisfied with it

Comment: @BlackEnigma thanks all the same, but my answer's got to go. As you said inheriting from core classes is not a great idea as discussed [here](http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes).

Comment: Thanks for the link, Haha that's a shame. No worries then, like I said no need to delete it

Answer (score 4):

I think your method works but it's your chaining that's the problem:

```
puts dna1.reverse_complement.reverse_complement
```

you've defined `reverse_complement` to return a string, and you can't call `String#reverse_compliment`.

Instead, write this:

```
dna2 = DNA.new(dna1.reverse_compliment)
puts dna2.reverse_compliment == dna1.nucleotide
```

Comment: I understand your answer, but the goal was to reverse the string for dna1 and find its compliment twice which would give you a value that is the same original value- which equals true. So, ATTGCC --> GGCAAT --> ATTGCC

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I use the same method twice for one instance in ruby?

Because you aren't using it for one instance. You are calling it on `dna1`, which is an instance of `DNA`, and then you call it again on the return value of `reverse_complement`, which is a *completely different instance* of class `String`.

Personally, I find it very confusing that a method called `reverse_complement` would return an object of a completely different type than the one it was called on. I would rather expect it to return a reversed and complementary instance of *the same type*, i.e. `DNA`:

```
class DNA
  def initialize(nucleotide)
    self.nucleotide = nucleotide.dup.freeze
  end

  def reverse_complement
    self.class.new(@nucleotide.reverse.tr('ATCG', 'TAGC'))
  end

  def ==(other)
    nucleotide == other.nucleotide
  end

  def to_s
    "DNA: #{nucleotide}"
  end

  protected

  attr_reader :nucleotide

  private

  attr_writer :nucleotide
end

dna1 = DNA.new('ATTGCC')
puts dna1.reverse_complement
# DNA: GGCAAT

puts dna2 = dna1.reverse_complement
# DNA: GGCAAT

puts dna1.reverse_complement.reverse_complement == dna1
# true
```